# Is it possible to make PHP print errors to a specific div?

Tags: php, html

I would like to have all PHP errors printed so a specific spot on my page, namely between:

```
<div id="errors">
</div>
```

I've seen custom error handling functions, but these do not seem to cover all error types. I can't even think of a way to do this with JavaScript, because the only similarity I see between errors is that they are enclosed mostly within b tags, and I would like to avoid regex if possible.

Comment: yah, post more code, with this code this answer is also valid add this line between the div tag `<?php echo $error; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have in the past gathered errors into an array as the page is loading, then at the bottom of the page when the page is finished loading, if there are errors, the php script will write a jQuery script to the div container similar to this:

```
<div id="errors"></div>
     <?php //if something goes wrong write error
          $_error['type'][] = 'error1'; ?>
<html stuff>
     <?php // something else goes wrong
          $_error['type'][] = 'error2'; ?>
<more html>
      <?php if(isset($_error)) { ?>
<script>
$('#errors').fadeIn('fast');
// This part you could loop if you had lots of types or come up with some
// elaborate javascript to populate your div
$('#errors').html('<?php echo implode("; ",$_error['type']); ?>');
</script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You could easily do this with HTML alone. You're bringing in jQuery which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: You are welcome to demonstrate the way you do it. Nothing is stopping you.

Comment: I can't answer because the question at this point in time is too broad. What errors need to be shown? What should happen when multiple errors arise? Before answering, you should understand what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Not to be combative, but all due respect, you had a method in mind when you commented "You could easily do this with HTML alone." You wouldn't say you had an alternative that was easier if you felt you couldn't answer the question at all as it was posed. You would have said what you just said in the first place. Point is, if you have a way to demonstrate HTML alone, the why not demonstrate it? I genuinely am interested in it because if it's a better way, I am open to learning it. I don't mean that in a sarcastic way either (as much as it sounds like it is).

Comment: Noah's answer is close to what I would have answered. Sorry if I came off as hostile. But when the OP only tags PHP and HTML, answers that include jQuery are often contested.

Comment: I can understand that. I know from experience on this I had the same problem where I wanted errors to be displayed explicitly on the top of the page and the only way I could think of doing it was some sort of javascript. I was willing to try anything to get it to work (even learning jQuery), but you have a good point. Some people are looking for a solution in the language they are most familiar with and maybe aren't willing to step outside of it. I will keep your concern in mind when I answer in the future. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an `$errors` array, you can add each error to that array and then iterate over it when displaying to the user.

Ex:

```
$errors = []; // add conditional statements below this and if the error arises, add it to the array.

foreach($errors as $error) {
   echo $error['value'] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion is to have an array which stores all the error information and a boolean variable (e.g. isDebugMode) that tells whether errors should be printed or not.

Then use a for-loop to print out all the errors inside of the div you want, formatting the output with interspersed html.